# How do I setCoders when doing an end-to-end test when my coder requires a KvCoder which requires a UnionCoder

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm working with the Java cloud dataflow SDK and I'm working on some end to end tests.

```
@Test
    public void testEndtoEnd() throws Exception {
        TupleTag<Entity> tag1 = aTagFromElsewhere1;
        TupleTag<Entity> tag2 = aTagFromElsewhere2;
        TupleTagList tags = TupleTagList.of(tag1).and(tag2);
        CoGbkResultSchema schema = new CoGbkResultSchema(tags);

        JoinEntities myDoFn = new JoinEntities();
        DoFnTester<KV<String, CoGbkResult>, Entity> fnTester = DoFnTester.of(myDoFn);     
        List<RawUnionValue> rawUnionValues = new ArrayList<RawUnionValue>();
        Date validThruDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000L);
        rawUnionValues.add(new RawUnionValue(0, aValidEntity1)));
        rawUnionValues.add(new RawUnionValue(1, aValidEntity2));
        CoGbkResult result = new CoGbkResult(schema, rawUnionValues);

        KV<String, CoGbkResult> aCoGbkPair = KV.of("Bleh", result);

        Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create();

        PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> input = p.apply(Create.of(aCoGbkPair))
                .setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), CoGbkResultCoder.of(UnionCoder, schema)));

        PCollection<String> output = input.apply(new FormatEntitiesForTsv());

        DataflowAssert.that(output).containsInAnyOrder(/**TODO: Create test data**/);
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that within the setCoder, I am using a KvCoder.of() which requires a UnionCoder. I'm not sure how to get this UnionCoder and I've looked at the class for it and it isn't accessible.

How do I work around getting this? (Alternatively, if there is a better way to go about getting the input, I am all ears).

Thanks and cheers :)

Comment: Hmm, why do you say UnionCoder is not accessible? It seems public to me - both the class and the factory method at https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/join/UnionCoder.java#L43

Comment: I'm not sure where that SDK would come in, I should have included this in the first place but I was using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/join/UnionCoder.java#L38

(Which is why I am thinking it's not public)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it's an oversight in the SDK - `UnionCoder` ought to be public, and it was made public in the Beam SDK some time ago. Your best option would be to either build your own version of the Dataflow SDK with this change, or wait for us to make the change in the github repo and wait for the next Maven release (I'll send a pull request and update this answer).

Comment: This was just merged and will be part of the next Dataflow release.